# Undefined index: query in, convert mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, undefined

problem 1.

error on line 9 in index.php "$error = getAct($_GET['error']);"

this is conncect.php

```html
<?php
$mysql_host     = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_dbname = 'db_nestle';
$link = mysqli_connect("$mysql_host", "$mysql_username", "$mysql_password", "$mysql_dbname") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
?>
```

this is function.php

```html
<?php
function getAct($string) {
 include 'connect.php';
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $string = stripslashes($string);
    }
 $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $string);
 return $string;
}
?>
```

index.php

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

include 'include/connect.php';
include 'include/function.php';
#Lihat cookies user, apakah masih ada atau masih berlaku
secure();
$error = getAct($_GET['error']);
?>
```

Problem 2 
show_table.php error line 4 and 5. "$id=$_GET['query'];"

this jquery in index.php

```js
function loadTable() {
 var lim = 10;
 var qry = $('input[name="cari"]').val(); // qry ada value dari input type text dengan nama "cari"
 $.ajax({
  url:"show_table.php", // URL Tabel yang akan di select
  type:"GET",  // Method yang digunakan = GET (Juga bisa menggunakan method POST)
  data:{query: qry, limit: lim}, // Kirim data ke "sales_on_pelanggan_tabel.php?query=qry" qry = input text nama "cari" sesuai dengan apa yang kita ketik di input text
  success: function(result){
   $("#divTable").html(result).css('margin-top','10px');  // Masukkan hasil dari pencarian ke kontent, dengan ID="divTable"
  }
 });
}
```

this is show_table.php

```html
<?php
include 'include/connect.php';
include 'include/function.php';
$id=$_GET['query'];
$q = $_GET['q'];
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
if($q){  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM User order by nama limit $limit";
 $query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
```

please help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

The undefined index notice means you're trying to access an array index that isn't declared. Use isset() to check first:

```
$error = (isset($_GET['error']) ? getAct($_GET['error']) : '');
$id = (isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : '');
$q = (isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '');
```

I would then add some fallbacks for when these values are empty.